# How do I parse a double and show it in an EdiText after calculation?

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner, please just tell me what Im doing wrong with a hint. Dont tell me the solution just a good hint.  This is my code:

```
package com.dietel.preserve;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "myApp";
double fedExPivot1 = 35.00;
double fedExPivot2 = 45.00;
double fed1=850.00;
double fed2= 750.00;
double fedAdd= 2500.00;
String p;
double convertedWeight;
double outShippingCost;
String s;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     EditText weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    p= weight.getText().toString();



    convertedWeight= Double.parseDouble(p);

    final EditText textvew= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

    Button calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

   calculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           outShippingCost =shippingCost(convertedWeight);
           s=Double.toString(outShippingCost);

           textvew.setText(s);


       }
   });


}

public double shippingCost(double w) {

    if (w < fedExPivot1) {

        w= w* fed1+fedAdd;
        w=w/100;

    } else if (w > fedExPivot2){
        w= w*fed2/100;

    }else if(w>= fedExPivot1){

        w= w*fed1/100;
    }



    return w;
}
}
```

I'm just trying to get a value from an editText and then convert it into a double and then show it inside another ediText after calculation. Please help me.

This is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.dietel.preserve.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:text="@string/weight"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:text="@string/sale_price"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="128dp"
    android:layout_height="39dp"
    android:text="@string/calculate"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.566"
    android:layout_marginTop="77dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText4"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_marginRight="53dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="137dp"
    tools:ignore="LabelFor,RtlHardcoded"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    android:layout_marginRight="53dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="LabelFor,RtlHardcoded"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="114dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/total_cost"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.992"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="112dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="256dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
    android:text="@string/enter_info2"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
    tools:text="Enter Info:" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="104dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="53dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="LabelFor,RtlHardcoded" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked for a hint: you're fetching the value of the first field in a wrong time, so when you click the button you're processing a wrong value. Examine *convertedWeight* carefully.

Comment: Awsome! Thank you! Thank you!